# Could not deduce (Applicative f0) when Applicative f is given

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble understanding why there are two independent `f` and `f0` Applicative constraints in code below (requires `reducers` package).

```
import Data.Semigroup.Applicative
import Data.Semigroup.Reducer
import Data.Semigroup

-- | Foo
--
-- >>> getMax $ foo ["abc","a","hello",""]
-- 5
foo :: [String] -> (Max Int)
foo = foldReduce . map (length)

bar :: (Foldable f, Monoid m, Reducer e m) => f e -> m
bar = foldReduce

m :: Max Int
m = unit (2 :: Int)

apm :: (Applicative f) => Ap f (Max Int)
apm = unit $ pure (2 :: Int) -- ambiguous Applicative!
```

I think that I need to somehow tell that I want `f0 ~ f` where `f0` is independently inferred by use of `pure`.

I tried to simplify:

```
u :: (Applicative f, Monoid m) => e -> Ap f m
u = undefined 

m :: (Applicative f) => Ap f (Max Int)
m = u $ (pure (2 :: Int))
```

It will compile once `e` is changed to `f e` so that contexts can "unify". But I don't know how to unify [with reducer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reducers-3.12.2/docs/Data-Semigroup-Reducer.html#t:Reducer) context.

My goal is to foldReduce with Applicative Semigroup (if that's possible at all) so that `length` will be replaced with effectful version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard solution is to use `ScopedTypeVariables` to announce that the `f` in the signature for `apm` and the `f` you want `pure` to produce are the same `f`. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Semigroup.Applicative
import Data.Semigroup.Reducer
import Data.Semigroup

apm :: forall f. Applicative f => Ap f (Max Int)
apm = unit (pure 2 :: f Int)
```

Don't lose the `forall`; it's a requirement of the extension to bring `f` into scope in the definition's body.

Comment: Is this because leaving out the `forall` will implicitly place it as `apm :: Applicative f => forall f. Ap f (Max Int)`?

Comment: @SimonShine No, there is no sensible rationale like that. It's just an arbitrary rule set in place to distinguish between variables that should be bound in the definition associated with that declaration and variables that shouldn't be bound. Many people even think the rule is backwards (variables should be bound by default and left unbound if they are explicitly universally quantified); the existing rule was chosen to be the opposite of that just so that turning on the extension would not change the meaning of any existing code, not for any deep theoretical reason.